# Is there a way to get all embedded objects in .xlsx file using xssf event mdel api

Tags: apache-poi, xlsx, xssf

Is there a way to get all embedded objects in .xlsx file using xssf event model api?

Usermodel has the method workbook.getallembedds...similarly is there anything in eventmodel?

This is an example in usermodel.I want to implement the same functionality using eventusermodel.Kindly help.

```
 for (PackagePart pPart : workbook.getAllEmbedds()) {
 String contentType = pPart.getContentType(); 
 if (contentType.equals(------)
```

Instead of xssfworkbook(in usermodel), in the eventmodel code i have a containerObject of type OPCPackage.

@Gagravarr : Thanks for your reply. I tried using the method suggested by you...but im unable to get the contents of the embedded excel.Could you please help me find out where I am going wrong.Here is a part of the code:

```
      ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings = new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(container);
      XSSFReader xssfReader = new XSSFReader(container);

      XSSFReader.SheetIterator iter = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator)xssfReader.getSheetsData();
      for(PackageRelationship rel : iter.getSheetPart().getRelationshipsByType(XSSFRelation.OLEEMBEDDINGS.getRelation()))
                  embedds.add(getTargetPart(rel));

          for (PackagePart pPart :getAllEmbedds()) {

              String contentType = pPart.getContentType();


              // Excel Workbook - OpenXML file format
               if (contentType.equals("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml")) {
                OPCPackage excelObject = OPCPackage.open(pPart.getInputStream());
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally all I used was this!

```
  ArrayList<PackagePart> parts = container.getParts();

  for (PackagePart pPart :parts) {

  String contentType = pPart.getContentType();


 if (contentType.equals("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably just to enumerate all the package parts, and find the ones that interest you from that

Alternately, the logic to identify embedded parts attached to a given sheet is pretty simple:

```
    List<PackagePart> embedds = new LinkedList<PackagePart>();

    // Get the embeddings for the workbook
    for(PackageRelationship rel : sheet.getSheetPart().getRelationshipsByType(XSSFRelation.OLEEMBEDDINGS.getRelation()))
            embedds.add(getTargetPart(rel));

    for(PackageRelationship rel : sheet.getSheetPart().getRelationshipsByType(XSSFRelation.PACKEMBEDDINGS.getRelation()))
            embedds.add(getTargetPart(rel));

    return embedds;
```

Comment: This is an example in usermodel.I want to implement the same functionality using eventusermodel.Kindly help.                  `for (PackagePart pPart : workbook.getAllEmbedds()) {
         
       String contentType = pPart.getContentType();
                
       if (contentType.equals(------) `

Comment: It says the function getTargetPart(rel) is undefined.I tried importing the package org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument but no use. Also kindly explain what you mean by enumerate all package parts

Comment: You'll want to pinch the code for that method out of POIXMLDocument. To enumerate all the parts, start at the root of the package and list it / get each set of relations recursively

Comment: Kindly respond to my question.I have edited the original question

Comment: Why are you ignoring all package parts except the sheet main one? The embedded objects you want won't be of that type!

Comment: Isnt this part checking for embedded sheetparts in each iteration? `for(PackageRelationship rel : iter.getSheetPart().getRelationshipsByType(XSSFRelation.OLEEMBEDDINGS.getRelation()))
                      embedds.add(getTargetPart(rel));`

Comment: U mean i should check for package parts in the OPCPackage container?Getting sheet parts wont help? Kindly provide a sample code if possible...Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried this. But the arraylist remains empty :( Please help!! `ArrayList<PackagePart> parts = container.getPartsByContentType( XSSFRelation.OLEEMBEDDINGS.getContentType());`

Comment: The concept of workbook is avoided in event api..so how do i do it??

Comment: You'll only find parts by a relationship from other parts that are linked to them. For your case, you'll need to get the sheet parts to be able to find the OLE Embedded ones. However, it's probably simpler to just get all parts in the file, and then check their types!